# Authlogic issue only in migration in rails 3 project

Tags: migration, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

I'm trying to run the following migration

```
def self.up
    add_column :users, :perishable_token, :string
    User.all.each { |u| u.reset_perishable_token! }
    change_column :users, :perishable_token, :string, :null => false

    add_index :users, :perishable_token
end
```

and the `u.reset_perishable_token!` code behaves strangely (no return value, doesn't change the database field). Consequently `change_column ..., :null => false` fails with

```
users.perishable_token may not be NULL
```

Even separating the migration into two doesn't do the trick either if I run them with just one rake command.

Part One

```
def self.up
    add_column :users, :perishable_token, :string

    add_index :users, :perishable_token
end
```

Part Two

```
def self.up
    User.all.each { |u| u.reset_perishable_token! }
    change_column :users, :perishable_token, :string, :null => false
end
```

Only if I run the first and second migration in separate rake processes everything runs fine.

What could possibly be the reason and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add...

```
User.reset_column_information
```

...after you have added the perishable_token to the users_table, otherwise the User model is out of sync with the database.

I think the User model would only be loaded once per 'rake db:migrate', so it wouldn't help to split the migration in two.